A short story about aliens befuddled by human (and, in general, terrestrial) sexual reproduction
I read this short story (or, possibly, novelette ?) at least 40 years ago, probably more. I read it in French, in a collection, but I am almost sure it was a translation from English.
An alien explorer is observing Earth. On his world, and all the worlds his civilisation have ever visited, only asexual reproduction by budding exists. So he is totally befuddled by the vague indications he can find about reproduction by "interaction" of two individuals of each of the two "different" forms of a single species. Not just humans but most (macroscopic) species on Earth, for that matter. He concludes that this makes Earth unique and extremely dangerous and that it should be destroyed. Note, however, that no description of the "interaction" is given, everything is extremely "decent".
But his superior does not believe him. His opinion is that men and women are too different, and thus belong to different species and that no such interaction is possible. To prove his point the explorer kidnaps one member of each "form" and try to have them "interact". Since the kidnapped man and woman are each married to a different person, they refuse to "interact". The superior concludes that the explorer is wrong and has him free the kidnapped persons. The alien ship leaves.
Once freed, the man and woman discuss what happened. Their adventure has created a link between them. Since their respective spouses are both away, well... No need to say more.
The explorer on the way out gives a last look at his ex-captives. He sees an "interaction" taking place but before his superior has time to see it the ship is too far.
I was reminded of this story by a comment on another question asking whether there was anything sexual in the very old  SF/Fantasy story I was looking for there. But SF/Fantasy was extremely puritanical at that time, as witness the extreme precautions in the story here.

Playboy and the slime god

I will add an answer if you want, but it's a duplicate.

Do answer before it is closed, so I can accept your answer !

OK, I'll post an answer now :-)

Everybody knows that random men and women would otherwise "interact" by default, if marriage wasn't an impediment.

As described in my answer to Short story; Aliens look for Playboy bosoms the story is Playboy and the Slime God by Asimov, aka What is this Thing called Love.
The story has appeared in many, many anthologies. I forget where I first read it, but the copy I used for the quote above was from Nightfall Two. It can be read online at the Internet Archive (thanks to user14111 for the link).
The ending you remember is:

Meanwhile, back in the spaceship, the crushed Botax was making a final effort to prove his case. While Garm prepared the ship for departure Botax hastily set up the tight-beam visiscreen for a last look at his specimens. He focused in on Charlie and Marge in her apartment. His tendril stiffened and he began flashing in a coruscating rainbow of colors. “Captain Garm! Captain! Look what they’re doing now!” But at that very instant the ship winked out of Time-stasis.


Look at this   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48903/short-story-where-aliens-test-random-earthling-couple-for-procreation   Isn't this one the first time the question was asked, and thus the one above is a dupe, too....
